# Atom error highlight - disable

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error, atom-editor

I am new to Atom and want to disable the error highlight below. I've looked through `Settings -> Core`, and `Themes` for highlight options, as well as online for suggestions, but found none.

[image]

I opened Atom in developer mode so I could inspect element and it seems to be a linting thing. Are there standard linters or error checkers in Atom that I can disable to remove the red highlight? Or at least change the highlight color?

[image]

There doesn't actually appear to be an error with the code so I'm not sure why it's complaining anyway.

Comment: might be missing a self closing tag on the line above (can't see the end)

Comment: You have some bad nesting with your HTML, it's a syntax error.. As Atom is telling you, could you share the actual source for brevity please ?

Comment: it doesn't mean exactly that's an error that impedes your code from running properly, you might just be missing a closing tag( e.g. you are not closing a `<div>`) I advise against disabling that highlighting, it's useful for actual errors. I suggest installing the package Beautify, it will help with arranging the code https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify

Answer (score 0):

You can change the CSS of an element by modifying it in Atom's `styles.less` file. For example, if you wanted to change the background color of some error messages to purple, you would add this CSS to `styles.less`

```
atom-text-editor {
  .invalid, .illegal {
    background: purple;
  }
}
```